# How to convert pdflatex to word

Tags: tex-core, conversion, msword, latex2html, latex2rtf

I have a tex document with math formula, figure, tikz drawings.

What is the best way to convert tex to doc format.

I tried with latex2rtf, pandoc, ...
but nothing works.

Can someone write step by step tutorial to convert tex to doc?

Thanks.

**Edit**

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx, hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
                shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{standalone}


\begin{document}
\section{Objave}

\input{grafi}


\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{viri}
\end{document}
```

grafi.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{standalone}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx, hyperref}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
                shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Teorija grafov}
bla bla $(G)$ bla $V(G)$ bla $E(G)$.bla aaaaaaaaaaa $v,u$ $\epsilon$ $V(G)$ aaaaaaaa $(u,v)$ $\epsilon$ $E(G)$ aaa $u~v$. 

\begin{figure}[h]
\def\tkzH{130pt}
\def\tkzV{130pt}
\input{graf}
\caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa $V(G) = \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$ aaaaaaaa $ E(G) =  \{ \{1,2\}, \{1,5\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,5\},\{3,4\}, \{4,5\}, \{4,6\}\}$.}
\label{graf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

graf.tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
                shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{\tkzH}{\tkzV}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance   = 30pt]
  \tikzset{VertexStyle} = [shape          = circle,
                                 draw,
                                 %ball color     = white,
                                 text           = black,
                                 inner sep      = 2pt,
                                 outer sep      = 0pt,
                                 minimum size   = 24 pt]
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle}   = [black,
                                 double          = black,
                                 double distance = 0.5pt]
  \tikzset{LabelStyle} =  [%draw,
                                 %fill           = yellow,
                                 %text           = red,
                                 sloped, 
                                 anchor=center, 
                                 above]


                                  \node[VertexStyle](1){1};
                                  \node[VertexStyle, below right =30pt of 1](2){2};

                                  \node[VertexStyle, above right  = 30pt of 1](5) {5};
                                  \node[VertexStyle, right =  of 5](4) {4};

                                  \node[VertexStyle, right =  of 2] (3) {3};
                                  \node[VertexStyle, above right = 30pt of 4] (6) {6};

                                  \foreach \from/\to in {1/2, 1/5, 5/4, 2/3, 3/4, 4/6, 2/5}
                                        \draw[EdgeStyle] (\from) -- (\to);


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try `tex4ht`, command for conversion is `mk4ht oolatex filename`. math and figures should be fine, tikz probably would need some configuration. you should provide a minimal working example, so we can see the problems you found

Comment: Probably this is not the right place to ask this question :).

Comment: Do you really want to convert F-117 Nighthawk into Wright brothers' aeroplane?

Comment: No, I'm OK with tex., but I need to share with others.

Comment: @michal.h21 I added an example

Comment: Nowadays is easy to make comments in PDF files. So I suggest you to share the `pdf` and they could insert comments.

Comment: I need odf or doc

Comment: I know this does not solve your problem with equations  and figures, but a make-do solution for sharing is to convert your `pdf` to `txt` with `pdftotext`, open it in word or libre office and save it in `.doc` or `.odf`. If you use the `-layout` option it preserves your layout. It also extracts text from your figures and tikz images so they can be edited. Images and equations are however destroyed.  I do this when I send my manuscripts to my english proofreader who does not have latex. It is horrible for the eyes of the reader, but they choose to use word, not me. Send the `pdf` file also.

Answer (score 1):

Create with the `standalone` document class a single pdf image of your grafic which you then include with `\includegraphics` into your main document. Crate a pdf and then use https://www.gonitro.com/de/ to convert the pdf into a Word format. There is a trial version.